# How to wait for a Mac OS X application to fully activate

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

My application is a debugger and I need to frequently switch the active process between a target application and my debugger application as the user steps from one line to another within their code.  I am currently using the `SetFrontProcessWithOptions(…, kSetFrontProcessFrontWindowOnly)` call to accomplish this.

The problem I have is that the `SetFrontProcessWithOptions()` call returns before the application is fully activated.  `SetFrontProcessWithOptions()` returns when the process becomes the active process, but before its main window has been brought forward and made active.  If I call SetFrontProcess again too quickly to reactivate my debugger application, Mac OS X gets confused and the layering of windows becomes muddled.  Visually, the wrong window appears to be active and keyboard and menu focus is directed to what appears to be an inactive window.

I have tried using `GetFrontProcess()` after calling `SetFrontProcessWithOptions()` to poll, but `GetFrontProcess()` immediately returns the PSN that my code has activated with `SetFrontProcessWithOptions()` even though that process's windows are not yet fully activated.

Does anyone know of a way to determine when an application has become fully active with its main window ready to receive keyboard input?

Comment: I wonder if `NSRunningApplication *clientApp = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier: (pid_t)pid];`, then using Key Value Observing on `clientApp.active` would give you a better answer than the `GetFrontProcess()` polling?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I gave it a try, but like GetFrontProcess, `clientApp.active` reports YES before the app's windows are activated.